# Using regex in SQL (Amazon Redshift) to extract tag

Tags: sql, regex, amazon-redshift

I've been trying for a few hours to figure this out, but am stuck.

I'm trying to extract this substring

`dg`

from something like this

`agent/bond,am/dg,day/sunday,man/woman,exemption/yes,account/true`

or

`am/dg,agent/bond,day/sunday,man/woman,exemption/yes,account/true`

using regex in Redshift.

I got close with `regexp_substr(tags,'[(^am\/$)][^,]+')`, but it didn't work entirely.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: What version of Redshift are you using?

Comment: Not sure @TimBiegeleisen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We might be able to use `REGEXP_REPLACE` here with a capture group:

```
SELECT
    REGEXP_REPLACE(input, '.*\yam/([^,]+).*', '$1')
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: @DavidGarsia What exactly did happen when you ran my update query?

Comment: The output of your function is equal to the input.

Comment: Try using `$1` as the replacement instead of `\1`.

Comment: `REGEXP_REPLACE(tags, '.*am/([^,]+).*', '$1')` (so without `\y` and with `$`) works! Thanks!

Comment: do you know a good website where I can test Redshift (SQL) regex?

Comment: `Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.`

Comment: Thanks—Stack n00b here.

Answer (score 0):

How about this way with `SUBSTRING` along with regex **look-behind** and **look-ahead positive**?

**Explanation:** capture the tag that has `am/` before it and `,` after it i.e **dg**

```
SELECT
 SUBSTRING (
 'agent/bond,am/dg,day/sunday,man/woman,exemption/yes,account/true',
 '(?<=am/)(.*?)(?=,)'
 ) as tag;
```

**OR**

```
SELECT
 SUBSTRING (
 'am/dg,agent/bond,day/sunday,man/woman,exemption/yes,account/true',
 '(?<=am/)(.*?)(?=,)'
 ) as tag;
```

Comment: What about an input like `account/true,am/dg`?

Comment: The substring function doesn't seem to work in (my version) of Redshift, unfortunately. If I change the function to `regexp_replace`, I get the following error: `Invalid preceding regular expression prior to repetition operator. The error occured while parsing the regular expression fragment: '(?>>>HERE>>><=am/)(.*?'.` So I think in my version of Redshift, look-behinds and look-aheads aren't supported. (I also escaped the slash (`/` => `\/`, which didn't solve the problem.)